# How to determine the no of possible combinations in a table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssas

I have a table that has the following 4 dimension columns and 1 measure column `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`, `Col4`, measure

The cardinality of the dimension columns are `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` respectively.

In my application, a user can select any number of values in each column i.e. multi selection and I need to run a query to find the total no of measures for that combo.

So in theory the maximal number of possible combinations are `(2^a-1) * (2^b-1) * (2^c-1) * (2*d-1)` in the worst case.

Now I want to know how many actual combinations are possible from my real data set, which I presume would be lot less because not all combinations are possible in real life.

Is there some SQL query or any other way (using C# may be) to determine this number from actual data?

I have the file as `.csv` and also in my SQL server DB.

Here is an ex: for table with 2 dimension columns

User, Action, Requests

---

U1, A1, 10

U1, A2, 5

U2, A3, 4

The theoretical maximum combinations possible are:
(2^2) * (2^3) = 4 * 8 = 32

But in reality, the no of possible combinations are only 10

1. U1 + A1
2. U1 + A2
3. U1 + A1 + A2
4. U1
5. A1
6. A2
7. A1 + A2
8. U2 + A3
9. U2
10. A3

Comment: Just to make sure, if there are duplicate values in column A (say `A1, A2, A2`) is selecting both `A2`s the same as selecting just one of them?

Comment: yes! it's the same. For this purpose we can assume that use can select either A1 or A2 or both or none.

Comment: Can you edit the question and provide some sample data?  I want to be sure that I understand it correctly.

Comment: added an ex in the Question

Comment: @user330612 Not 32 possibilities?  What about U1/A3, U1/A1/A3, U1/A2/A3, U1/A1/A2/A3, U2/A1, U1/U2/A1, A1/A2/A3 ... U1/U2/A1/A2/A3?  What is the extra restriction that limits this to 10 possibilities.

Comment: U1 + A3 is not a possible combination coz User1 never did Action3. Similarly U2 + A1 and U2 + A2 are invalid coz User2 never did actions 1 and 2. U1 + A1+ A3 is a possible combination coz it means user1 has done either action A1 or A3. I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the number of distinct values for each column,  (call them `nA`, `nB`, `nC`, `nD`), the total number of possible selections is  `2^nA * 2^nB * 2^nC * 2^nD`.  It is `2^n` per column (and not `2^n - 1`) because each distinct value has 2 states (selected or unselected).  You can think of it like a binary string of length n.

You have a variety of ways to determine the number of distinct values per column.

- You can query the database itself

  `SELECT count(sub.colA) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT colA FROM Table) as sub`
- You can query the data you already have in program memory (with LINQ for example) once you read it in from your csv file

  `int nA = docs.GroupBy(x => x.colA).Count();`

Once you have all the numbers, just exponentiate and multiply away.  To avoid overflows you can look into things like [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: This is the theoretical no of combinations possible which I already mentioned. I want to know exactly how many combinations are possible in my particular dataset/table not the theoretical maximum

Comment: @user330612 These values are directly from your dataset .  What makes that theoretical?  Please explain in more detail what you mean by theoretical.

Comment: added details in the Q now